# Will sandboxing a program protect my computer from being damaged?

Tags: windows, security, sandbox, comodo-firewall

I've heard from a friend that Spotify got attacked by an hacker, which results in it "damaging the hard disks" and stealing private data of the computers where the program is installed. It allegedly does that through a backdoor, though it seems to be just a rumor, as no official communication of that was given by developers.

If I used [Comodo Sandbox](https://help.comodo.com/topic-72-1-451-4768-.html) from Comodo Internet Security, would that prevent the backdoor application from damaging or deleting data from the hard drive, or reading private data?

Comment: You can never be a 100% sure, but the purpose of sandboxing is exactly that. However, Spotify might need to read data from your system in order to work correctly—so preventing read access will probably not work, I suppose? But I'll leave the answer for someone who has used this kind of sandboxing before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sandbox may offer protection from some malware, but sophisticated malware may be able to bypass or escape a sandbox. E.g., see [The Final Sandbox #fail?](http://blogs.bromium.com/2013/07/27/the-final-sandbox-fail/) which notes "No sandbox can protect an OS that is itself vulnerable" and "Do not rely on any sandbox to protect your users from attack".